# issues in reading google text document with google apis

Tags: java, gdata

I am trying to use following code to read a Google text document. But the value returned is a stream with garbage characters instead of the real contents. How can I fix this.

```
for (DocumentListEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {  
    String docId = entry.getDocId();
    String docType = entry.getType();
    URL exportUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/"
        + docType
        + "s/Export?docID="
        + docId
        + "&exportFormat=doc");

    MediaContent mc = new MediaContent();
    mc.setUri(exportUrl.toString());

    MediaSource ms = client.getMedia(mc);
    InputStream inStream = null;


    try {
        inStream = ms.getInputStream();
        int c;
        while ((c = inStream.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)c);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            inStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick read of [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html), it looks like you are reading the raw bytes of a Microsoft Word-encoded document.

Try changing the `&exportFormat=doc` to `html` or `txt` and see if the output makes more sense.

Comment: No the document is creating on google docs itself using the option create a text document. it is not a word document uploaded to google docs

Comment: It doesn't matter how the document was created. The API is exporting the document in [.doc format](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/reference.html#ExportParameters) because you are specifying doc as the export format.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the files you are trying to print out have some other encoding but you're printing them byte by byte in ASCII way. I would try to read the whole stream as byte array and then convert it to string using some other encoding (e.g. UTF8).